# Onload event for devexpress grid

Tags: devexpress

I need to know the `event` which triggers when a `devexpress` grid is loaded, or when I move from one page to other.

I need to add on that event some code that adds a div element to a column from the grid.
Right now I have added to

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var node = document.createElement("div");       
     var y = document.getElementsByClassName('cssForColumn dxgv');
     for (var item in y)
     {
         var aNode = $(y[item]);
         aNode.wrapInner("<div class='documentColumn'></div>");
     }
```

and it is working ok, but only when the grid is loaded initially. 
I have tried like this:

```
  $(".gvPartners_DXMainTable").load(function () {
     alert("Handler for .change() called.");
 });
```

with:

```
window.onload = function () {
     alert("test");
 };


document.getElementById("gvPartners_DXMainTable").onchange = function () {    
    alert("hello");
 };
```

but I did not manage to make it work properly
This is the grid:

[image]

Comment: are you talking about dxDataGrid or ASPxGridView?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [ClientSide Events of the ASPxGridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.GridViewClientSideEvents.members)

Basically you have to use the *Init*

```
     <dx:ASPxGridView ..............>
        <ClientSideEvents Init="function(s, e) { 
                               //Do your work here
                                }" />
     </dx:ASPxGridView>
```